oracle with clause assign value from previous query table
I need to use a value from previous query result in the second query while using with clause
example
with xtable as (
select t1.column1,
       t1.column2,
       t1.column3,
       t1.column4
from table1 t1
where t1.column1 in (1,2)
and t1.column4 = 'ut'
), ytable as 
(
select t2.column1,
       t2.column2,
       t2.column3,
       t2.column4
from table1 t2
where t2.column4 = xtable.column2 
)select * from xtable,ytable


Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement ("use a value from previous query result in the second query" does not explain which value or how you want to use it); and the expected output.

On a side note: Commas in the from clause are a thing of the past. This syntax was used in the 1980s and early 1990s, but since SQL92 we have been using explicit joins instead, e.g., from xtable cross join ytable.

You can add xtable in second query as :
with xtable as (
select t1.column1,
       t1.column2,
       t1.column3,
       t1.column4
from table1 t1
where t1.column1 in (1,2)
and t1.column4 = 'ut'
), ytable as 
(
select t2.column1,
       t2.column2,
       t2.column3,
       t2.column4
from table1 t2,xtable x
where t2.column4 = x.column2 
)


ORA-32039: recursive WITH clause must have column alias list

@sam - you would only get that error if you referenced the CTE within itself - i.e. if you'd done what's shown here but used ytable instead of xtable. With consistent names it works. (Though I'd recommend using ANSI join syntax, not this older syntax.)

@sam did you use alias as I used ,xtable x and referred to it x.column2 ?

You do not need to use sub-query factoring (WITH) clauses and can simplify the query to:
SELECT t1.column1 AS column1_1,
       t1.column2 AS column2_1,
       t1.column3 AS column3_1,
       t1.column4 AS column4_1,
       t2.column1 AS column1_2,
       t2.column2 AS column2_2,
       t2.column3 AS column3_2,
       t2.column4 AS column4_2
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table1 t2
       ON (t2.column4 = t1.column2)
WHERE  t1.t1.column1 IN (1,2)
AND    t1.column4 = 'ut';

If you did want to use a WITH clause:
WITH xtable AS (
  SELECT column1,
         column2,
         column3,
         column4
  FROM   table1
  WHERE  column1 IN (1,2)
  AND    column4 = 'ut'
),
ytable AS (
  SELECT column1,
         column2,
         column3,
         column4
  FROM   table1
)
SELECT *
FROM   xtable x
       INNER JOIN ytable y
       ON (y.column4 = x.column2)


or if you did want to CROSS JOIN the two tables (which is what xtable,ytable means) then:
WITH xtable AS (
  SELECT column1,
         column2,
         column3,
         column4
  FROM   table1
  WHERE  column1 IN (1,2)
  AND    column4 = 'ut'
),
ytable AS (
  SELECT column1,
         column2,
         column3,
         column4
  FROM   table1
  WHERE  column4 IN (SELECT column2 FROM xtable)
)
SELECT *
FROM   xtable x
       CROSS JOIN ytable y


it just an example

@sam "it just an example" is not a constructive comment as it does not tell me what you think the issue is or where improvements can be made. Please edit your question to include a [MRE] and explain what sample data you have and what the expected output is for that sample data and then you can have a solution that fits your data. But unless you give a detailed explanation of your "just an example" then your question (and comments) do not give any pointers for what a "better" answer should look like.
